# GROUP_CONCAT multiple fields with a different separator

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Is it possible to do something like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(user, price SEPARATOR ', ') AS items
```

The result is `John3.99, Mike24.99`

What I need is something like:

```
John - 3.99, Mike - 24.99
```

Basically use another type of separator for price field.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user, ' - ', price) SEPARATOR ', ') AS items
```

Or just

```
GROUP_CONCAT(user, ' - ', price SEPARATOR ', ') AS items
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT CONCAT(user,',',Price SEPERATOR) 
  ORDER BY items 
  SEPARATOR ';'
)
```