# GROUP_CONCAT multiple fields with a different separator in ARRAY

Tags: mysql

The following code is working perfectly :

```
$aColumns = array( "t.tablename", "r.book_hours", 
    "GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN r.reserveday = CURDATE() THEN r.formtime ELSE NULL END ORDER BY r.formtime ASC) AS oldBookTime");
```

But when I add multiple fields from this tutorial [StackTutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816859/group-concat-multiple-fields-with-a-different-separator/38817784)

I edit the code become :

```
$aColumns = array( "t.tablename", "r.book_hours", 
    "GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN r.reserveday = CURDATE() THEN r.formtime, '-', r.book_hours ELSE NULL END ORDER BY r.formtime ASC) AS oldBookTime");
```

It shows error:

> ```
> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '-'
> ```

Is it I have to escape `, '-',` ? How to escape it?

Comment: You're passing multiple columns within a THEN. Did you mean to `... THEN CONCAT(r.formtime, '-', r.book_hours) ELSE ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't escaping that is the problem, is that the value following `THEN` must be a single scalar value, not a list of values.

Change this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN r.reserveday = CURDATE() 
THEN r.formtime, '-', r.book_hours 
ELSE NULL END ORDER BY r.formtime ASC) AS oldBookTime
```

To this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN r.reserveday = CURDATE() 
THEN CONCAT(r.formtime, '-', r.book_hours) 
ELSE NULL END ORDER BY r.formtime ASC) AS oldBookTime
```

(I inserted linebreaks for the sake of formatting this answer, but they're optional.)

Answer (score 0):

In the `CASE` statement, you're using 3 results in the `THEN` branch. This is syntactically wrong. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) you can find the documentation for the CASE statement.

If I get what you want to achieve, you can use the `CONCAT()` function (documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)) to concat your values, this way:

```
$aColumns = array( "t.tablename", "r.book_hours", 
    "GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN r.reserveday = CURDATE() THEN CONCAT(r.formtime, '-', r.book_hours) ELSE NULL END ORDER BY r.formtime ASC) AS oldBookTime");
```